# How to integrate CMake projects with Qt and Vcpkg and make them compatible with different compilers?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have a Widget QT project that uses Mingw compiler. And I also have a project that uses vcpkg.cmake. I want to turn these two cmake projects into a single project, but I cannot integrate them because different configurations are used. Due to the different compiler problem, I cannot add the QT project to my project that uses vcpkg.cmake because it cannot find the desired compiler. How do I integrate these two projects that use different compilers?

Some part of QT cmakefile.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(deneme3 VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)
```

some part of glv cmakefile.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Prohibit in-source builds
if ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "In-source builds are prohibited.")
endif ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

project(glv NONE)
```

Comment: so is your question how to use vcpkg with mingw? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/platforms/mingw

Comment: @AlanBirtles Actually, I want to integrate the qt structure into other cmake project. In this way, I aim to add the 3D image I obtained from the other cmake project to the QT mainwindow and display it there.

Comment: Then you'll need to change your qt project to use the same compiler as your other project